# Faster way to propagate huge data in datatable jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, postgresql, datatables

I have a customer module and I have this Customer List. I am using Laravel 5 and this package http://datatables.net/. I'm using it coz it has a built-in search and sorting. So what happen is when I load the page I am making a ajax request to query all records in my `customers` table then propagate all of that in a table using `datatables` package/plugin. Problem is when I have too many records something like 20,000. The page will not respond. I think it takes too much processing. So here's my jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "api/customer/all", 
type: 'GET',
success: function(result){
var myObj = $.parseJSON(result);
//console.log(myObj);
    $.each(myObj, function(key,value) {
        var t = $('#CustomerList').DataTable();
        t.row.add( [
            value.id,   
            value.firstname,
            value.lastname,
            value.gender,
            value.phone_num,
            value.postcode,
            value.country,
            "<a class='btn btn-small btn-info' href='<?php echo URL::to('customer').'/';?>"+value.id+"/edit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>",
            "<form method='POST' action='<?php echo URL::to('customer').'/';?>"+value.id+"' accept-charset='UTF-8' class='pull-left' >"+
            "<input name='_method' type='hidden' value='DELETE'>"+
            "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>"+"</form>",
        ] ).draw();

    });
}});
```

Then the route

```
Route::get('api/customer/all', 'CustomerController@apiGetCustomers');
```

Controller function

```
//$customers = Customer::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id ASC;";  
$data = DB::connection('pgsql')->select($query);

return json_encode($data);
```

You see I'm also using Eloquent before to fetch data but it sucks handling huge amount of data so I use Query Builder instead. I think what took it slow is the jquery coz I can fetch all the data fine and fast. How do I propagate it faster? I'm using Postgre 9.3 SQL.

Comment: Have you tried that : https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php ?

Comment: Why don't you use some kind of pagination? Datatables plugin supports it natively

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes i am using pagination. Problem is the propagating of all records in the datatable is slow.

Comment: What do you mean by `the propagating of all records in the datatable is slow`??? Using pagination, you should only display to user few datas at once, not 20000. So on each new table page, you should resend a request to get only relevant data to be displayed, not all

Comment: @A.Wolff I understand what you're saying. You mean per page I will limit the query to let's say 100, then since datatables has bulti in pagination, when they select page 2 then I'll query again for the next 100? Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Dom operations can be very slow.  You may want to add rows in intervals which might be better for the user's experience.  So maybe use setTimeout() and play around with number of records and milliseconds to wait.  Might be worth a shot.

```js
(function loadDataTable() {

    var data,
      curIndex = 0,
      t = $('#CustomerList').DataTable(),
      AMOUNT_ROWS = 100;

    function addMoreRows() {

      var i, value, limit = curIndex + AMOUNT_ROWS;

      if (limit > data.length) limit = data.length;

      for (i = curIndex; i < limit; i++) {

        value = data[i];

        t.row.add([
          value.id,
          value.firstname,
          value.lastname,
          value.gender,
          value.phone_num,
          value.postcode,
          value.country,
          "<a class='btn btn-small btn-info' href='<?php echo URL::to('customer').'/';?>" + value.id + "/edit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>",
          "<form method='POST' action='<?php echo URL::to('customer').'/';?>" + value.id + "' accept-charset='UTF-8' class='pull-left' >" +
          "<input name='_method' type='hidden' value='DELETE'>" +
          "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>" + "</form>"
        ]).draw();

        curIndex = i + 1;

        if (curIndex != data.length) setTimeout(addMoreRows, 200);  // give browser time to process other things

      }
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "api/customer/all",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(result) {
        data = $.parseJSON(result);
        addMoreRows();
      }
    });
  }

})();
```

Comment: Also, I might add, you're creating a form element on every row I think... this is probably not the best approach.  use one function and just call the function with parameters when you want to submit data and use ajax.  I haven't used a form element in maybe 10 years.

Comment: First thing I would do is just remove that last cell and see what performance is like then... I would bet that's your problem area.  If it is, find a way to defer rendering of that cell... like, maybe an onShown event or something, then render the cell only when the user is actually looking at the row.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but I can't fully understand it. Can you give me example?